# Changing the name of a sharepoint list programmaticaly

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to change the "name" of a sharepoint document library (not the title). I have found a way to do it from sharepoint designer: http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=52 What I need is to do this programmaticaly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Name" is an actual root folder of the list. So you need to rename it

```
            using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://server"))
            {
                //open the relevant site
                using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb("TestSite"))
                {
                    //loop through the lists
                    foreach (SPList list in myWeb.Lists)
                    {
                        //when we find the correct list, change the name
                        if (list.RootFolder.Name == "OrigListName")
                        {
                            //move the root folder
                            list.RootFolder.MoveTo(list.RootFolder.Url.Replace("OrigListName", "OrigListName_New"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, only got the original list name from the list also: list.RootFolder.MoveTo(list.RootFolder.Url.Replace(list.RootFolder.Name, newname));

Comment: I would suggest an update on the folder object after the MoveTo call. I ran into issues without it (refetching the library still showed it has the old URL untill the update was called).